# Get month difference only if the days are the same

Tags: php, mysql, date, pdo, timestamp

How can I get the difference of months between two dates in MySQL only if the days are the same? Here is what i have so far but it doesn't work because when the days are not the same, it still works:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2019-05-05', '2019-06-05')
Output: 1

TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2019-05-05', '2019-06-22')
Output: 1 // should NOT work because days are 05 and 22. Needs to be the same dates
```

I can obviously do:

```
DAY('2019-05-05') = DAY('2019-06-05') AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2019-05-05', '2019-06-05')
```

but how can I do it in one function?

Thanks!

Comment: You can explode date strings and compare day/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SUBDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate)/`ADDDATE`/[`DATE_SUB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)/`DATE_ADD` will handle this well:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2019-06-22', INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = '2019-05-05'

| DATE_SUB('2019-06-22', INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = '2019-05-05' |
| ------------------------------------------------------: |
|                                                       0 |
```

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2019-06-22', INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = '2019-05-22'

| DATE_SUB('2019-06-22', INTERVAL 1 MONTH) = '2019-05-22' |
| ------------------------------------------------------: |
|                                                       1 |
```

See the [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=fa18fac990cfa9fc763da040610d5a79)

Comment: @timmy balk it will work only if the INTERVAL is Fixed...  therefore you have to use multiple functions as I have done below if you want a date difference between 2 dates columns... I know you want to avoid it but there is no more option in MySQL

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can get it by using the below query...

```
 select DATEDIFF('2019-06-22', '2019-05-05') as Diff from table_name where 
    day('2019-06-22') == day('2019-05-05');
```

using column name...

```
 select DATEDIFF(dateColum2, dateColum1) as Diff from table_name where 
    day(dateColum2) == day(dateColum1);
```

From PHP you can get it like below...

```
$dateValue1 = '2019-05-05';
    $dateValue2 =  '2019-06-22';
    $time1=strtotime($dateValue1);
    $day1=date("D",$time1);

    $time2=strtotime($dateValue2);
    $day2=date("D",$time2);

    if($day1 == $day2 ) {
    $seconds_diff = $time2 - $time;
    }
```